# How can I disable my touchpad/prevent accidental clicking while typing on Fedora 24?

Tags: fedora, touchpad

My problem is this:

While I'm typing on my XPS13 9350, it often happens that I touch the touchpad with my palm, causing the cursor to jump around and therefore I'm typing in the wrong place from then on.

**What I've already tried:**

- Turning Palm detection on in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/touchpad.conf
- Using    syndaemon -i 2
- Using synclient to turn off the touchpad alltogether
- Using cinnamon settings to disable the touchpad while typing

All of these actions had absolutely no effect at all.

**Best case** would be one of these 2:

- I can use the touchpad to move the cursor while I'm typing but I can't click
- Palm detect works and the touchpad doesn't even notice anything because it detects my palm correctly

**Also acceptable** would be:

- As long as I'm typing the touchpad is being disabled completely

Why has nothing I've tried so far had any effect and how can I get this to work?

Comment: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/7485/how-disable-the-touchpad/
Have you tried using this `toggle script`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, thanks to what you posted I actually found the right answer withing a few minutes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2316240

Aswer is here. Problem is that somehow a generic touchpad is detected even though a different touchpad is actually in use. All the commands I tried went to the generic touchpad which doesn't actually exist, so that's why nothings worked.

Tried the fix and now it's all good.

Comment: Thanks! A couple of years later and this answer is still awesome :)

Answer (score 6):

The key to disable touchpad while typing doesn't exist anymore in the Gnome registry.

First install dconf-editor -

`sudo dnf install dconf-editor`

then create a key in dconf editor using this command on terminal.

`dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/disable-while-typing true`

It will create `disable-while-typing` as key and will set it to true.

This worked for me on fedora 23, Gnome 3.18. I will also work on fedora 24.

**Update:** Tested and this also works on Fedora 24,33.

Comment: this disables the trackpad but trackpad buttons are still alive :-(

Comment: I guess, trackpad button can not be pressed accidentally while typing without knowingly putting enough pressure on it. :-)

Comment: This worked for me on Fedora 33